# How to decode JSON with JSONDecoder by reflected class type in Swift 4.2?

Tags: swift, reflection, jsondecoder

Can't find correct way to call `decode` method with reflected class type. Got `ambiguous reference` error on it.

```
class EntityTwo: Decodable {
    var name: String = ""
}

class EntityOne: Decodable {
    var value: String = ""
}

struct Entity: Decodable {

    var entity: String
    var payload: Any

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case entity
        case payload
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        entity = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .entity)
        let entityType = NSClassFromString("MyFramework." + entity) as! Decodable.Type

        payload = try container.decode(entityType, forKey: .payload)
    }
}
```

Got problem in:

```
payload = try container.decode(entityType, forKey: .payload) -> Ambiguous reference to member 'decode(_:forKey:)'
```

In background it used to receive different entities from socket:

```
{
    "entity": "EntityOne",
    "payload": {
        "value": "EntityOneValue"
    }
}

{
    "entity": "EntityTwo",
    "payload": {
        "name": "EntityTwoName"
    }
}

public func websocketMessage(data: Data) {

    let entity = JSONDecoder().decode(Entity.self, from: data)
    ...   
}
```

Comment: Where do you get your error? Using your code I get `Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Decodable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols`

Comment: `payload = try container.decode(entityType, forKey: .payload)` -> `Ambiguous reference to member 'decode(_:forKey:)'` (Swift 4.2)